# How to use voximplant supervision call in single scenario

Tags: javascript, scenarios, voximplant

So here I want to use supervision calls to find out the conversation that happens between client_call and operator_call in the same scenario. I'm a bit confused on how to capture multiple calls in the same scenario between supervisor_call and operator_call and client_call.

Here is the code in my scenario.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
require(Modules.Conference);

const voice = VoiceList.Google.id_ID_Standard_C;
var client_call;
var operator_call;
var supervisor_call;
let conf;

VoxEngine.addEventListener(AppEvents.CallAlerting, e => {
    client_call = e.call;

    let dest = e.destination.split("#");

    if(e.callerid != "supervisor") {
        if(isNaN(dest[1])) {
            operator_call =  VoxEngine.callUser({
                username: dest[1],
                callerid: e.callerid,
                displayName: e.displayName,
                video: false,
                scheme: e.scheme
            });
        } else {
            operator_call = VoxEngine.callSIP("sip:"+dest[1]+"@sip2.b3networks.com",
            {
                "callerid": e.callerid,
                "regId": 859,
            });
        }
    } else {
        supervisor_call({"callerid":e.callerid,"destination":dest[1],"displayname":e.displayName,"scheme":e.scheme});
    }

    VoxEngine.easyProcess(client_call, operator_call, () => {});

    operator_call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Connected, callConnected);
    operator_call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Disconnected, callDisconnected);
    operator_call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Failed, callFailed);
});

function playbackFinished(e) {
    client_call.answer();
    VoxEngine.sendMediaBetween(client_call, operator_call);
    VoxEngine.removeEventListener(CallEvents.PlaybackFinished);
}

function callConnected() {
    operator_call.say("Halo, panggilan ini percobaan dari Askarasoft Indonesia", voice);
    operator_call.addEventListener(CallEvents.PlaybackFinished, playbackFinished);
}

function callDisconnected() {
    operator_call.hangup();
    client_call.hangup();
    VoxEngine.terminate();
}

function callFailed() {
    // any additional attemp if call fails

    client_call.hangup();
    operator_call.hangup();
    VoxEngine.terminate();
}

function supervisor_call(params) {
    if(isNaN(params.destination)) {
        supervisor_call = VoxEngine.callUser(
            {
            username: params.destination,
            callerid: params.callerid,
            displayName: params.displayName,
            video: false,
            scheme: params.scheme
            }
        );
    } else {
        supervisor_call = VoxEngine.callSIP("sip:"+params.destination+"@sip2.b3networks.com",
        {
            "callerid": params.callerid,
            "regId": 859,
        });
    }
    

    conf = VoxEngine.createConference();
    supervisor_call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Disconnected, supervisor_call_disconnected);
    supervisor_call.addEventListener(CallEvents.Failed, supervisor_call_failed);

    client_call.sendMediaTo(conf);
    operator_call.sendMediaTo(conf);
    conf.sendMediaTo(supervisor_call);
    VoxEngine.sendMediaBetween(client_call, operator_call);
}

function supervisor_call_disconnected() {
    VoxEngine.sendMediaBetween(client_call, operator_call);
    VoxEngine.destroyConference(conf);
}

function supervisor_call_failed() {
    VoxEngine.sendMediaBetween(client_call, operator_call);
    VoxEngine.destroyConference(conf);
}
```

I want to use supervision calls to find out the conversation that happens between client_call and operator_call and capture multiple calls in the same scenario.

By multiple calls, I mean that one scenario can be used for both regular calls and supervision calls.